# Proof of the convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Assume f:[a,b] $\Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, f(x) $\geq$ 0 for all x $\in$ [a,b], and M = sup{f(x) : x $\in$ [a,b]}. Show that

$$\left\{\left[\int_a^b [f(x)]^n dx \right] ^{\frac1n}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$$

converges to M.

Not only can I not prove this, I can't see intuitively why this would be true. Can someone explain anything about this to me?

Sorry the formatting is poor. While I'm at it, can whoever edits this tell me how to make it so squiggly brackets *actually show up* in formulas? They also just screw up the whole thing and put a box around it. Ideally there would be big squiggly brackets around everything except the bounds n=1 to infinity.

Comment: To make a bracket use \{ or \}. This is because { and } have other uses in TeX. To make autosizing brackets type \left\{ and \right\}. These must come in pairs (one left bracket and one right bracket).

Comment: This is false.  Take the function $f(x) = 1$, $a = 0$, $b=10$.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, this is telling you that the $L^{\infty}$ norm is the limit of the $L^p$ norms ($p$ as a pos. integer here )as $p\rightarrow \infty $

Comment: @user710587 But $\lim_{n\to\infty}10^{1/n}=1$.

Comment: Ok! I stand corrected. I'm writing up a solution.

Comment: Hint for the intuition: instead of the integral consider a finite sum.

Comment: thanks for the tip @IBWiglin.

Answer (score 1):

What a super problem this is.  Let $a_n = (\int_a^b f(x)^{n}\, dx)^{n^{-1}}$ be the expression you wrote in your question.

1. Observe that $f \leq M \implies a_n \leq M$. EASY
2. We will now show that for each $\epsilon>0$ that there exists some $N(\epsilon)$ such that whenever $n>N(\epsilon)$ we have that $a_n \geq M-\epsilon$. HARDER

Therefore, 1 and 2 together imply that for sufficiently large $n$, we have $M-\epsilon \leq a_n \leq M$.  This proves that $a_n \rightarrow M$.

Let's show 2. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set, we know two things: a) $f(c) = M$ for some $c \in [0,1]$; and b) there exists some $.5>\delta>0$ such that $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta) \implies f(x)\geq M-\epsilon$.

Therefore we have that $(\int_a^b (f^n))^{n^{-1}} \geq (\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} (f^n))^{n^{-1}} \geq (\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} (M-\epsilon)^n)^{n^{-1}} = ((M-\epsilon)^n(2\delta))^{n^{-1}} = (M-\epsilon)(2\delta)^{n^{-1}}$.

Now we have a fact: $(2\delta)^{n^{-1}} \nearrow 1$.

Therefore choose an $N(\epsilon)$ such that $n>N(\epsilon) \implies (2\delta)^{n^{-1}}>\frac{M-2\epsilon}{M-\epsilon}$.  Letting $n>N(\epsilon)$ now gives that $(\int_a^b f^n\, dx)^{n^{-1}} \geq M-2\epsilon$.

As $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary, the claim is proven.

For the record, I have no intuition on this, I just wanted to grab onto the supremum and see what happens.

Comment: This trick comes up all the time in real analysis. The intuition is that when we are raising $f(x)$ to a very large power, the region very close to the maximum of $f$ will constitute almost all of the area under the curve of $f^n(x)$. So we simply forget about the rest.